# Lambda calculus: evaluation by value would not terminate but normal evaluation terminates

Tags: computer-science, lambda-calculus

I'm wondering if it is possible that evaluation by value would not terminate but normal evaluation terminates.

Because in normal evaluation we will evaluate until we reach a normal form meaning that we cannot evaluate further, but in by-value, we evaluate everything except the last lambda and we evaluate all the arguments even the ones that are not used.

So I don't think it would be possible because normal evaluation is more eager than by-value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is possible that evaluation by value (which fires a $\beta$-redex only if the argument is a value, i.e. an abstraction or a variable) does not terminate but normal evaluation (which fires the leftmost-outermost $\beta$-redex) terminates.

Consider for instance the term $(\lambda y. I) (\Delta \Delta)$, where $I = \lambda x.x$ and $\Delta = \lambda x. xx$. We have:

- normal evaluation $\to_\beta$ terminates because $(\lambda y. I) (\Delta \Delta) \to_\beta I$, since there are no free occurrences of the variable $y$ in $I$;
- evaluation by value $\to_{\beta_v}$ does not terminate because $(\lambda y. I) (\Delta \Delta) \to_{\beta_v} (\lambda y. I) (\Delta \Delta) \to_{\beta_v} (\lambda y. I) (\Delta \Delta) \to_{\beta_v} \dots$, since evaluation by value forces to evaluates $\Delta \Delta$ first, and $\Delta \Delta \to_{\beta_v} \Delta \Delta \to_{\beta_v} \dots$.